# Car bluetooth receiver with CANBUS for speed sensitive volume and steering wheel controls?

Tags: bluetooth, can-bus

After reading on some canbus control packages, I'm confident that a raspberry pi based bluetooth receiver can be made so that it understands vehicle speed and increases volume as the vehicle speeds up (to compensate for road noise), also reacts to steering wheel volume / track commands.

Unfortunately, I've never dealt with Pi, so I don't even know the proper keywords to search for. Has something like that been figured out? Either at a DIY level, or as a ready made / pre-build solution.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? ... it almost sounds like you are trying to control a vehicle speed and steering with a Raspberry Pi

Comment: `I've never dealt with Pi` ... Raspberry Pi is a Linux computer ... have you dealt with Linux?

Comment: 1. I'm trying to replicate the speed sensitive volume feature the car has, so I can get rid of the otherwise useless factory radio. And retaining steering wheel control ot volume/track would be nice.

2. I've dealt and deal with Linux and have some knowledge but it gives me anxiety and a need for a drink.

Comment: ok ... please edit your post to make it clear that you are talking about controlling the audio device in the vehicle ... `understands vehicle speed and adjusts volume accordingly` can easily mean that you are asking about adjusting the vehicle speed level ... this is an international site and language translation can pick misleading words

Comment: It appears you have not done your research. Try "pi detecting car speed", you might even find your answer.